# Google play console - App access for google testers

Tags: google-play, maui, google-play-console

My application created in MAUI does not require any login or authorization. However, it contains partially paid content.
I put my apps in google play. And now I have to go through a few steps. One is app access, and it says: "Google must have access to all parts of the app to check it out. If access to certain parts of the app is restricted - such as requiring login details - you'll need to provide Google access instructions."

Now what should I do with this fact. Should I put a button that, which can be used, for example, to enter a code that will give access to all paid features in my application, so that testers can test it?
I will add that my paid features are just different categories that the user can play and they do not differ from the free ones other than a different text value.

My application is not connected to any API (for example unable to check how many time someone used my free acces) and I am now afraid that by sharing such code, some tester could share it somewhere else. Can I be sure that it is safe and my data will not leak anywhere about how to use paid content.

Comment: how do users access paid content?

Comment: Using google play payments. In MAUI I using CrossInAppBilling.Current. Examples of access restriction features include: subscriptions, but it is not well described whether it is all subscriptions or other than those made by Google Play. I don't have subscriptions I have only single payments.

Comment: I assume Google Play reviewers are capable of creating test purchases if needed

Comment: Ok, well, unfortunately, the documentation of this is an A4 page and there is no such information. And it says they can block the app if testers can't test it.

Comment: If they don’t approve iit in the first pass you can update with additional info